# How to over-ride a file in a plugin?

Tags: plugins, functions, child-theme, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I have a third party plugin that I'm using for a photo gallery (NextGen).  However, with my black background, the loader gif animation looks pretty bad.  I found a better loader gif and replaced the one from the plugin.  I already know this is not ideal because the next update of the plugin will overwrite my custom gif.

The gif is located at: `/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/images/loader.gif`

Is there a clever way to leverage my child theme's `functions.php` file to tell this plugin to use a different URL for the gif?

As far as using my child theme's CSS to override, that would be easiest if it was a viable option.  However, the loader's URL is not coming from the plugin's CSS file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a rewrite rule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^path-to-images/ajax-loader\.gif /path-to-replacement.gif [L]
```

Make sure to set this above the WordPress rules.

Comment: Man, now it feels like I over-complicated it. Great solution!